# Trouble adding observer to NotificationCenter in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having trouble adding a notification observer in Swift 3.0.

Code like so:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: .playerItemDidPlayToEndTime, name: Notification.Name(AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification), object: playerItem)
```

I am getting the error: `"Cannot invoke value of type Notification.Name.type (aka NSNotification.Name.Type) with argument list (NSNotification.Name)"`

With:

```
AVF_EXPORT NSString *const AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification      NS_AVAILABLE(10_7, 4_0);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotification.name/1386566-avplayeritemdidplaytoendtime) it should be just `NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martin R Commented, name argument should be:

```
NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime
```

And complete code will be:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: .playerItemDidPlayToEndTime, name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playerItem)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not in this case but also important: you need to `import AVFoundation` in your file. In Swift the imports are mostly not necessary anymore, so I tend to forget them when needed ...